# new to CPP: Compiler error

Tags: c++

Compilation fails with the following output.

Any thoughts please..

```
PStore.cpp
PStore.cpp(169) : error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
PStore.cpp(169) : warning C4091: '' : ignored on left of 'bool' when no variable is declared
PStore.cpp(169) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'inline function header'
PStore.cpp(170) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
PStore.cpp(170) : error C2556: 'int PStore::getVersion(std::string &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'bool PStore::getVersion(std::string &)'
    ../include\PStore.h(48) : see declaration of 'PStore::getVersion'
PStore.cpp(170) : error C2371: 'PStore::getVersion' : redefinition; different basic types
    ../include\PStore.h(48) : see declaration of 'PStore::getVersion'
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
bool PStore::getVersion(std::string& version)
{
    AMPI_INFO("[API]");

    return getVersionNoLogging(version);
}
bool PStore::getVersionNoLogging(std::string& version)
{
    version = AMPI_PStore_VERSION " " __DATE__ " " __TIME__;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It helps to post the offending code.

Comment: In your case you can see that it's complaining about lines 169 and 170.  You should post those lines (with some sort of flag identifying which line is which), plus at least a few lines of context.

Comment: The error might be on the line before the code you show. The compiler complains about a missing `;` on line 169. Perhaps that's the end of the class declaration? A class should end with `};`.

Answer (score 5):

Please post your code so that all errors can be explained.

One of the errors is obvious however: you can't have two functions with the same parameters and the same name.

In your case you have `int PStore::getVersion(std::string &)` and `bool PStore::getVersion(std::string &)`, which is not legal.

Either change the name of one of the functions, or change the type or number of parameters of one of the functions.

Comment: Don't you mean one to be bool ? It says so on this line:

PStore.cpp(170) : error C2556: 'int PStore::getVersion(std::string &)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'bool PStore::getVersion(std::string &)'

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: whoops, fixed.